# Selecting a file from a directory randomly and then display it

Tags: php, php-5.4

I have a directory which contains several text files. What I'm trying to do is to randomly select one of the files and then display it. Here's what i got so far, but i still haven't managed to get it working. Any idea's? Thanks.

```
<?php
function random_pic($dir = 'wp-content\files')
{
    $files = opendir($dir . '/*.txt');
    $file = array_rand($files);
    return $files[$file];
}

while(!feof($file)) { 
        echo fgets($file) . "<br />";
    }

    fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: You may have permission issue. Check your error log.

Comment: Try [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scandir` will put all elements in the directory into an array. Then use `array_rand` to choose a random element from the array.

```
$dir = "/path/to/pictures/";
$dirarray = scandir( $dir );
unset($dirarray [0]);
unset($dirarray [1]);
$content = file_get_contents( $dir . $dirarray[array_rand($dirarray )] );
echo $content;
```

The `unset` commands are to remove `.` and `..` from the array.
This would for example result in echoing `picturename.jpg`.

Comment: This gets file names in the directory. i need it to display the content. I'm not sure how to use the output of the array with the fopen.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt read your question correctly. Ive updated my response now so that it will post the content of a random file instead

Answer (score 0):

use function name with parameters in while loop condition and check function returning a file name or not. Check the following link for detail http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

Use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function to get all files in a directory, and then take a random element from that array and return it. Then read the file and echo its content.

```
function get_random_file($dir = 'folder_name')
{
    $files = glob($dir . '/*.txt');
    $file = array_rand($files);
    return $files[$file];
}

   $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
   $theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
   fclose($fh);
   echo $theData;
```

Comment: $myFile is not identified in  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');.

Comment: Make sure that you have to give here directory path also.
For example :- fopen("/home/".$myFile, "r");
Please check the fopen php manual.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong slash in your directory.

```
$dir = 'wp-content\files'
```

should be

```
$dir = 'wp-content/files'
```

It should be forward slash not back slash. Also check permission of the directory that you are accessing.